# Turning off iPad & taking screen shots

Tags: ipad

Since doing the last upgrade/update on my iPad, I can no longer lock it or take screens shots. Now because I can’t lock it, I can’t back it up. Why is this happening & what need to be done so I can go back to redoing both?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue with my iPad. What version of iOS or iPadOS is it running? A fix for me was going to Recovery Mode, and using connecting the device to your Mac or Windows PC and then using iTunes. When the dialog appears saying that there is a problem with your device, select Update. You can also restore a back up. Here is an article: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211078. This covers recovering the passcode but the steps mentioned can help solve this.